# How to set ManagedBy property for Security Group via C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I am having issues updating the ManagedBy property for Security Groups (works fine for Distribution Groups).  I receive the following error: '{"You don't have sufficient permissions. This operation can only be performed by a manager of the group."}'

I am running with an account that has full access.  The command works when running via PowerShell just not via C#.  Here is the command I am running.

```
Command cmdCreateDR = new Command("Set-DistributionGroup");
cmdCreateDR.Parameters.Add("Identity", "GroupName");
cmdCreateDR.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck"));
Collection<PSObject> manByUsers = new Collection<PSObject>();
manByUsers.Add(new PSObject("domain\\UserName1"));
manByUsers.Add(new PSObject("domain\\UserName2"));
cmdCreateDR.Parameters.Add("ManagedBy", manByUsers);
Collection<PSObject> resultsEx = RunPowerShellCommand(cmdCreateDR);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BypassSecuirtyGroupManagerCheck is a switch and the way your using it your passing it in a bool set to false which won't achieve your desired results. You should be doing something like

```
SwitchParameter switchpara = new SwitchParameter(true);
cmdCreateDR.Parameters.Add("BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck", switchpara);
```

Cheers
Glen